# Material-UI theme-able component library

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

We have a Material-UI component library that we're attempting to make themeable by the 'parent' application.

For example:

```
Parent app:
<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
   <ExternalComponent/>
</ThemeProvider>
```

```
Component library:
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    root: {
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.neutral.dark,
    }
}));

const ExternalComponent = ({ children }) => {
    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
            <div>
                <Menu />
            </div>
            <div className={classes.headerColumn}>
                <Header />
                <Content>
                    { children }
                </Content>
            </div>
        </div>
)}
```

The "ExternalComponent" fails in the useStyles function because `theme.palette.neutral.dark` does not exist.

Edit:
Just to clarify the ExternalComponent is in a *separate package*.  So it is built entirely separately from the 'Parent app'.

Comment: please add your theme file also..

Comment: @Rajiv it's not relevant.

Comment: it is. in `makeStyles` you're trying to access `theme.palette.neutral.dark` color which is not by default in material-ui. And I guess this might be the reason..

Comment: You're right, it's in the custom theme that is in the theme file.  It works inside the app, just not in the library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my current workaround.  I'm not a huge fan, but it's functional...

```
Parent app:

<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
   <ExternalComponent theme={theme}/>
</ThemeProvider>
```

```
Component library:
const useStyles = theme => makeStyles(({
    root: {
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.neutral.dark,
    }
}));

Component: 

const ExternalComponent = ({ theme, children }) => {
    const classes = useStyles(theme);

    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
            <div>
                <Menu />
            </div>
            <div className={classes.headerColumn}>
                <Header />
                <Content>
                    { children }
                </Content>
            </div>
        </div>
)}
```

Comment: anything new on this point since then, i am stuck at the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Could you use the Material-UI `useTheme()` hook?

[useTheme](https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/#accessing-the-theme-in-a-component)

It should give you access to the theme inside of your component.

Comment: Unfortunately useTheme only gets the default theme...